# bash - elif statement returns same value regardless of input

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, terminal

I'm writing a shell script to take a number between 1 and 7 in the command line and return the corresponding day of the week. My code currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a number between 1 and 7 >"
read number
number=$n
if [ "$n"=="1" ]
then
echo "Monday"
elif [ "$n"=="2" ]
then
echo "Tuesday"
elif [ "$n"=="3" ]
then
echo "Wednesday"
elif [ "$n"=="4" ]
then
echo "Thursday"
elif [ "$n"=="5" ]
then
echo "Friday"
elif [ "$n"=="6" ]
then
echo "Saturday"
elif [ "$n"=="7" ]
then
echo "Sunday"
else
echo "error"
fi
```

this returns "Monday" regardless of the input. If I add spaces either side of the == then it returns "error" regardless of the input! I've tried various things but cannot work out why

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Your awk code is certainly wrong: you get a value in the `number` variable but then you use another variable in comparisons (variable `n`). Variable `n` seems to be undefined.

Comment: @Cyrus it tells me the issue is in line 4 `number=$n`. I think the value it's reading, aka `number`, is not being assigned to `$n` but I don't understand why

Comment: See Jdamian's answer.

Comment: @Jdamian because I try to assign the value `number` to `$n`. If I remove `number=$n` and replace all occurrences of `$n` with `number` then the problem is the same as described in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following lines of your code

```
read number
number=$n
```

with these

```
read number
n="$number"
```

**update 1**: the bash comparisons in the format `[ "$n"=="x" ]` always return the code 0 (`true`), no matter the `x` value because the test `[ string ]` checks whether `string` is NULL or not. In other words, as no blank is used, the first `if` sentence of your code is always `true`, no matter the values of variable `n` and the values of `"x"`

Comment: then do I use `$n` for my comparisons? e.g. `if [ "$n"=="1" ]`

Comment: On bash, for interger comparisons this would be more correct `if [ "$n" -eq 1 ]`. Please note the space between all elements.

Comment: @JamilSaid did have spaces before and produced a different error. Anyway, added changed that and it all works now. Thanks!

Comment: `read` sets a variable just the same as an assignment. You can simply write `read n`, or keep `read number` and compare `$number` below.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same thing as Jdamian but it appears to be insufficient so since you are working with number it would be prefable to work with -eq instead like this:

```
if [ $n -eq 1 ]; then echo "Monday"; elif [ $n -eq 2 ]; then echo "Tuesday"; elif [ $n -eq 3 ]; then echo "Wednesday"; elif [ $n -eq 4 ]; then echo "Thursday"; elif [ $n -eq 5 ]; then echo "Friday"; elif [ $n -eq 6 ]; then echo "Saturday"; elif [ $n -eq 7 ]; then echo "Sunday"; else echo "error"; fi
```

you can replace the ; by a new line if you don't like the one liner format

on a different note, if a mega messy if like that isn't necessary, i would suggest using a case instead for a better readability:

```
case $n in
    1) echo "Monday" ;;
    2) echo "Tuesday" ;;
    3) echo "Wednesday" ;;
    4) echo "Thursday" ;;
    5) echo "Friday" ;;
    6) echo "Saturday" ;;
    7) echo "Sunday" ;;
    *) echo "error" ;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks for this. The examples of case statements I've covered so far didn't demonstrate what they did as clearly as this so I hadn't really considered it as an option. Generally I do prefer things to be as neat and concise as possible!

Comment: however for this to work, you do need Jdamian answer and assign the value of number to n instead of the other way around because the way you wrote it, you a assigning the value of read to number, then you redefine number by assigning the value of $n which is an undeclared variable nulling the value of number

Answer (score 1):

An array may be simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
day=(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday)

read -p "Please enter a number between 1 and 7 >" n
echo "${day[n-1]}"
```